# Ctrl+= opens the alpha input instead of below-script

Tags: keyboard, free-form-input

When trying to type "traditional style" inputs such as integrals or sums, I follow the tutorial and type

<kbd>Esc</kbd> sum <kbd>Esc</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> n=1  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>%</kbd> 10 whatever

However, when I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> it opens the (annoying and useless) alpha interface, and I am forced to use either textual input or use the palette.

I'm running Mathematica 8 on Fedora. Any ideas?

Comment: Let me complement your question by mentioning that in earlier versions of Mathematica (7, 6, 5, etc.) CTRL-= let one write under an expression, similarly to how CTRL-7 put the cursor above an expression.  This is also annoying for me, but I haven't taken the time to figure out how to do it in 8 yet.

Comment: Another comment: if all you want is enter input to be interpreted, you can use subscript/superscript  (CTRL-_ and CTRL-6).  This doesn't *look* the same as over- and under-expressions but it functions the same way when the system interprets your input

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut for underscripts has now been changed to <kbd>ctr-4</kbd> (<kbd>ctr-$</kbd>). So, to enter your `Sum[expr, {n, 1, 10}]`, you should type

<kbd>esc</kbd>`sum`<kbd>esc</kbd>
<kbd>ctr-$</kbd>`n=1`<kbd>ctr-%</kbd>`10`
<kbd>ctr-space</kbd>`expr`

Another option is to type the overscript <kbd>ctr-&</kbd> first and then use the <kbd>ctr-%</kbd> shortcut to move to the underscript position.

Not all of the tutorials have been updated (and if you feel like it, you can submit a bug report to WRI about the oversight that you noticed). That said, the main documentation page on [Typing Underscripts](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TypingUnderscripts.html) does use the correct shortcut (as does the [Underscript page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Underscript.html)).

By the way, I also still find myself pressing <kbd>ctr-=</kbd> for underscript and getting frustrated. But I don't think that I'd go as far as to claim that the Wolfram|Alpha interface is completely useless...

Comment: +1 received the `new answer loaded` message two seconds before I submitted. We now have a new record for the `new answer loaded` message latency:34 minutes :) Deleting my answer.

Comment: For the record: the `Ctrl+$` combination does $not$ produce an underscript on a sum inside an in-line math cell within a text cell. It just gives an ordinary subscript.

Comment: @kguler: The `MenuSetup.tr` info in your post is worth having on the site. Someone who finds this page *might* be looking for a way to change the default keys. In fact, given @yohbs' opinion of W|A he might want to revert the the `ctrl-=` shortcut.

Comment: @murray: For the record: Mathematica simply copies the LaTeX convention for inline maths. It does this so that the line spacing does not look stupid. In LaTeX this can be overridden by using `\displaystyle` or explicit `\limits`. In Mathematica, select the sum and use the Option Inspector to search for and set `LimitPositioning` to `False` in the `UnderOverBoxOptions` subsection. (This can also be set manually by looking at the underlying box expression (`Shift-Ctrl-E`) and wrapping a `StyleBox` with the option `UnderoverscriptBoxOptions -> {LimitsPositioning -> False}` around the sum)

Comment: @Simon, Mr.Wizard, Sjoerd, thank you for your suggestions to  undelete my answer (just undeleted and updated my post.)

Comment: @murray: If you always want the limits in inline math to be the over/under type, then you can change the defaults in the stylesheet. If you want to know more, then ask a new question on the site.

Answer (score 14):

In this context it might be useful to remark that if you enter

<kbd>esc</kbd>sumt<kbd>esc</kbd>

you'll get a complete sum template with your cursor already at the bottom:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I feel this is much easier than going through the other shortcuts.

The same works for products: <kbd>esc</kbd>prodt<kbd>esc</kbd>

[image: Mathematica graphics]

indefinite integrals: <kbd>esc</kbd>intt<kbd>esc</kbd>

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and definite integrals: <kbd>esc</kbd>dintt<kbd>esc</kbd>

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The 't'-s at the end of the shortcuts probably stands for 'template'. At least it works as a mnemonic for me that way.

Comment: Again, this method still doesn't automatically give you sub- and superscripts below and above the summation if you try to put it into a separate paragraph as a display. Another instance of how inferior Matheamtica is to LaTeX for correct mathematical typesetting.

Comment: @murray The question was about input, not text. Mathematica isn't that good in movie editing and making tea either; what's your point? Did you actually read Simon's reaction to your comment under his answer?

Comment: Yes, of course I read Simon's reaction. I made my "for the record" comment and the follow-up lest anybody reading this thread be misled into believing that Mathematica would position the scripts in a separate line of text, as if in a LaTeX math-display. And I said it because some folks advocate for Mathematica as a publication medium.

Comment: @murray: Again, Mathematica positions the limits exactly the same way as LaTeX does. Both will use over/underscripts for displayed math and super/subscripts for inline math. So I don't think that anyone can see what your point is.

Comment: @murray: Maybe you're confused about what displayed math is... you do know that in Mathematica you need to put such math in a separate `DisplayFormula` cell? Think of it as the equivalent of a LaTeX `equation*` or `align*` environment. You can also use `DisplayFormulaNumbered` in order to have automatic numbering.

Comment: @Simon: the `DisplayFormula` style still does $not$ do what LaTeX does with sum, integral, etc., namely, automatically position lower- and upper-limits below and above the big symbol (with the user just typing them as usual). Of course using the Basic Math Assistant, Writing Assistant, or Classroom Assistant palette will insert the whole template with display-math-like positioning into a `DisplayFormula` cell. And unfortunately, if you try to copy that cell and put in in-line on a separate line of a Text cell, the positioning reverts to the in-line type.

Comment: Of course the `Ctrl+$` and `Ctrl+%` trick $will$ work in a `Displayformula` cell.

Comment: @murray: If your point is that Mathematica will not display superscripts and subscripts as over and underscripts, then I agree with you. But so what! Expressions in Mathematica are more than just typeset - they also try to be unambiguously interpreted. It has to be more careful than LaTeX does. As for the copying of displayed math into an inline cell, the behavior is exactly the same as LaTeX, so get over it! This is my last comment on this matter.

Answer (score 7):

As the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>%</kbd> behaves as before (it toggles between `Subscript` and `Superscript`, between `Underscript` and `Overscript`), you can  use it instead of any special short cuts for `Underscript`: Enter your `Overscript` first, and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>%</kbd> to enter `Underscipts`. Of course, this is more challenging a habit switch than the alternative (switch to the new short cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>, that is.)

If you wish to change the short-cut for `Below` from 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>  to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> 
once-and-for-all, you need to do some editing in two text resource files in the directory

> ```
> $InstallationDirectory\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\Windows
> ```

First, in the file `MenuSetup.tr` find the following line that assign the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> short- cut to Free Form Input:

```
  MenuItem["Inline Free-form Input",
  KernelExecute[AlphaIntegration`LinguisticAssistant[InputNotebook[]]], 
  MenuKey["=", Modifiers->{"Control"}], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic],
```

I modified the last line above by adding an additional modifier key as follows:

```
MenuKey["=", Modifiers->{"Control","Command"}], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic],
```

to assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> as  the new Wolfram|Alpha short-cut.

Next, you can change the following lines in the same file similarly:

```
MenuItem["&Above", "Above", MenuKey["7", Modifiers->{"Control"}]],
MenuItem["&Below", "Below", MenuKey["4", Modifiers->{"Control"}]],
```

The second file is `KeyEventTranslations.tr` in the `TextResources` directory. It shows the current key event short-cuts:

```
 Item[KeyEvent["7", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Above"],
 Item[KeyEvent["&", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Above"],
 Item[KeyEvent["Keypad7", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Above"],
 Item[KeyEvent["$", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Below"],
 Item[KeyEvent["4", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Below"],
 Item[KeyEvent["Keypad4", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Below"],
 Item[KeyEvent["%", Modifiers -> {Control}, CellClass ->  BoxFormData], "Otherscript"],
```

I added the following line to this portion of the file

```
Item[KeyEvent["=", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Below"],
```

Now I have both the new short cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> and my old friend <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> for `Underscript` so that I can phase out of my old habit at my own pace:)

Of course, you need to save the files after your changes, and re-start Mma for the changes to take effect.

**Caution:** Casual playing with the resource files may be dangerous. It is easy to get carried away and corrupt your installation. **Make backups before changing any file**.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thank you for the edit and the upvote... But I was about to delete this answer as it is the same as, but 34 minutes later than, Simon's answer.

Comment: For some reason I didn't notice this comment until now.  I think this answer adds value and I would rather you did not delete it.